# How to express "The sum of degrees of vertices is even" in Predicate Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If $V(x)$ represents $x$ is a vertex and $S(z)$ represents sum of $z$ and $E(y)$ represents "$2$ times the number of edges" then can we write

$\forall x(S(x)) \rightarrow E(y)$ ?

Comment: What does sum of z mean?

Comment: 2 times the number of edges of what?  The whole graph?

Comment: Are x,y, and z all vertices?

Comment: I have to write "The sum of degrees of vertices is even" in Predicate Logic, the statements like V(x) are my formulation. I don't know whether I have written them correctly or not. @WilliamElliot